# In Phoenix Framework, why is there a redundancy of "schemes" and migration?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

You can not modify the schema without creating migration? Why is there migration and schemes? Why not just migration? It seems redundant.

Comment: When you say schema, do you mean DB schema or Ecto.Schema? In other words, is your question about the need to specify the properties in your models in addition to specifying when creating migrations, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Migrations` are convenient ways to alter your database schema. Each migration can be considered as a new version of your database. You add or remove tables, columns, or entries as per your requirement. 
Where as `Schema` is the current state of the database.

**It is recommended to alter your schema through migrations**, since you know the history of how you altered your database and it provides features like rolling back your migration.

Consider a newly generated phoenix app,when we run `mix ecto.create`, there are no tables currently just an empty database. As per our requirements we want a  table say `user`. We create a *migration* using `mix ecto.gen.migration add_users_table`.

```
def change do
  create table(:users) do
    add :name,       :string
    add :age, :integer
    timestamps
  end
end
```

We can migrate(apply) this *migration* using `mix ecto.migrate`.
Now we have some schema, which basically consists of the user table and its relevant columns we added. We could rollback this migration if we think its inappropriate using `mix ecto.rollback`, which will undo the schema changes

Comment: I think by schema he's referring to Ecto.Schema, but I could be wrong. The fact you have to specify properties in your model structs rather than just have them defined at runtime (a la ActiveRecord) has irritated some engineers coming from the Rails world that I've known.

Comment: @CodyPoll you might be right,  I'l edit or delete my response, need more info from the questionire

Comment: I am beginner in the world of programming and frameworks. I did not understand what the coderVishal spoke, but his answer almost fully answered my question. What was missing was completed by Thao Hoang. Thank you all! Automatically translated.

Answer (score 4):

You may not need to to create a migration to modify the schema. The schema only defines what is there in the database at that moment (columns, relations). You can change all of that using database console such as `psql` directly or other tools like `pgadmin` and then do the corresponding change in the schema model, without any migration file : )

```
defmodule Pxblog.Post do
use Pxblog.Web, :model

alias Pxblog.User

schema "posts" do
  field :title, :string
  field :body, :string
  belongs_to :user, User
  has_many :comments, Pxblog.Comment

  timestamps
end

@required_fields ~w(title body)
@optional_fields ~w()

def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
end
end
```

For example, you can add a column `author_name` to the table by running `alter` query directly, and just add `field :author_name, :string` to the schema block.

Comment: If someone is a beginner I would not recommend this, having migrations will give you a lot of benefits in the long run.

Comment: +1! IMO, this is only for the case when you have to handle a legacy database or share the db with some other apps : )